# Can we evaluate the alternating sum of the digits of an irrational number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, irrational-numbers

Suppose you had a summation $\sum(-1)^na_n$, where $a_n$ is the $n$th digit of $e$ and $a_0=2$.

I know it diverges, but I want to know if its possible to evaluate anyways.  Since it is alternating, we can use a number of ways to attempt to evaluate it, an Euler transform, take partial sums and averaging...

Any ways, it comes out to be

$$\sum(-1)^na_n=2-7+1-8+2-8+1-8+2-8+4-5+9-\dots$$

There is no clear pattern to me, and when I attempted a few methods to evaluate it, well, I failed, as in I do not know how to find the $n$th digit of $e$ so easily.  (And I don't quite understand how to perform an Euler Transform on this sequence, perhaps they must be monotone increasing?)

More generally, is it possible to take the digits of an irrational number and summate them to a finite value?  Like an easier sequence from $\sqrt2$?

Comment: I'd say it will diverge $\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n a_n \approx \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{N})$ as any random sequence of $\pm 1$

Comment: and it is as usual, you consider the power series $f(z) = \sum_n a_n z^n$, clearly $f(1/10) = e/10$, and $f(z)$ converges for $|z| < 1$, but has at least a singularity on $|z| = 1$ (its radius of convergence is $1$ since all the $a_n$ are $< M = 10$ and infinitely many of them are $\ge m = 1$), clearly it has a singularity at $z=1$, and you are asking about $\lim_{z \to -1^+} f(z)$, I think it has good chances to exist

Comment: @user1952009 yes, but I mean to evaluate it regardless of the fact that it fails the term test (or other convergence tests).  I intend on treating it as a divergent series, like $$1-1+1-1+1-1+\dots=1/2$$And it is rather late, so I shall have to say farewell for today.

Comment: It depends on the irational number.  But in general an irational numbers digits will not have any coherent pattern (why would it)  as all sequences  of digits must make irrational numbers and pattern less sequences infinitely out number patterned ones.  But take .01001000100001..... it's clearly irrational but the sum you describe will alternate between 1 and 0. (Although no sum will be "clean" or converge as values with distinct integer values will always cause flucuations.)